# Gnome mail client? For Exchange, GMail and MS Live accounts

Tags: gnome, email, thunderbird, evolution

Hello what email client am I supposed to use in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04? I just switched to gnome and I can see there are online accounts to add all my three mail accounts (Exchange, GMail and MS Live).

I can't see any mail client preinstalled. The calendar works great integrated in top menu.

I tried to install evolution with evolution-ews. The accounts are detected at startup which also is great, but there seem to be a bug which causes evolution to be unable to access the accounts after sleep or if you go to the switch user menu or switch networks.

Solution is to reboot to get access to accounts.

The error messages in evolution are:

```
Failed to connect account "account@live.com".
The reported error was "Failed to authenticate: Timeout was reached".

Failed to connect calendar 'account@gmail.com : account@gmail.com'
Timeout was reached

Failed to connect account "account@exchangeserver.com".
The reported error was "Source 'account@exchangeserver.com' doesn't support prompt for credentials".

Failed to connect 'account@gmail.com'
Failed to obtain an access token for 'account@gmail.com': Timeout was reached

Failed to connect calendar 'account@gmail.com : Holidays in Sweden'
Failed to obtain an access token for 'Holidays in Sweden': Timeout was reached

Failed to connect calendar 'account@gmail.com : account@gmail.com'
Failed to obtain an access token for 'account@gmail.com': Timeout was reached

Failed to connect account "account@gmail.com".
The reported error was "Failed to authenticate: Timeout was reached".
```

I don't know if this is a related bug, but it seems to be close https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1259434

Anyone else have another usable mail client?

Comment: I just discovered Geary. It looks great! Simple GUI and also a gnome app. Unfortenly it doesnt look like its supporting Exchange :'(

Comment: It looks like [lately](https://github.com/GNOME/geary/commits/master?after=e6fe0b3cbdc5de96b9b77dd037a6de380936c461+0) Geary was being developed mostly by a single person, who recently took a break :).